# How to store item's keywords in Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to store in MongoDB some elements, characterized by a 'categories' and 'subCategories', something like:

{"item1": {"categories":"restaurant, bar", "subCategories":"fish, steak, coffe"}}

My question is, what is the best way to store this item, considering that I will search for keywords like 'bar' or 'fish' ? Is it better store all the keyword as one String (case 1) or as an array of Strings (case 2) ?

```
  {"item1": {
            "categories"   : "restaurant, bar", 
            "subCategories": "fish, steak, coffe"
           }
  }
```

Or

```
{"item1": 
          {
           "categories"   : ["restaurant", "bar"], 
           "subCategories": ["fish", 'steak", "coffe"]
          }
}
```

Which gives the best performance ?

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: which of the two possibilities is the best?  Save all the keywords as one String, or as an array of Strings?  Which gives the best performance ?

Comment: Store as array. Because if you store as comma separated, later you will have to split the string and might have to perform other operations as well. Go will arrays.

Comment: however the split will be performed client side (I guess in most cases). I'd like to improve server search performance

Comment: Array would be the best solution then comma separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the second option.

```
{"item1": 
          {
           "categories"   : ["restaurant", "bar"], 
           "subCategories": ["fish", 'steak", "coffe"]
          }
 }
```

This enables you to do queries on the DB side with opereators like `$in` `$not` etc. Your first options will require you to do search either as full text search or in the client side, and that will be slower.